# How do I convert a character code in one coding system (windows-1252) to another?

Tags: character-encoding, character-decoding

I'm working on a script that needs to decode some markup in `.rtf` format.

Within `rtf`, as documented [here](https://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading46), the escape sequence `\'` followed by hex digits specifies a character by numeric code, with the catch that ***this is not a Unicode code point but a character in the `Windows-1252` character set*** (at least in the files I'm dealing with).

So the question:

What is the cleanest way to convert a numeric code in a different character set to a Emacs multibyte character or string.  ***Please note that I would like to avoid converting the whole file;  I only want to convert a sequence of numeric codes in one encoding (`Windows-1252`) to an equivalent sequence in another one.***

The following code more or less works but seems needlessly verbose and wasteful:

```lisp
    (defun convert-rtf-byte (byte)
      (let ((file (make-temp-file "rtf")))
        (with-temp-file file
          (insert (unibyte-string byte))
          (setq coding-system-for-write 'no-conversion))
        (with-temp-buffer 
          (let ((coding-system-for-read 'cp1252))
            (insert-file-contents file)
            (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max))))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how I missed this in the manual, but the function I was looking for is `decode-char`, e.g. `(decode-char 'cp1252 #x93))`.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is in the manual; the manual should be the first place you look. Questions should ideally indicate what you searched for in the manual. Use `C-h i` to open the Info viewer, which lets you read all of the manuals installed on your system.

The functions you need are documented in [chapter 34.10.7 Explicit Encoding and Decoding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Explicit-Encoding.html) of the Emacs Lisp Manual. I found it by choosing the Elisp manual from the list, then using `C-s` to search for “encoding”. The first result was for Base64, so I skipped that one. The second is for I/O, which you want to avoid. The third is the one you want.

You should read the whole thing, but probably you want this function:

```
 -- Function: decode-coding-string string coding-system &optional nocopy
          buffer
     This function decodes the text in STRING according to
     CODING-SYSTEM.  It returns a new string containing the decoded
     text, except when NOCOPY is non-‘nil’, in which case the function
     may return STRING itself if the decoding operation is trivial.  To
     make explicit decoding useful, the contents of STRING ought to be a
     unibyte string with a sequence of byte values, but a multibyte
     string is also acceptable (assuming it contains 8-bit bytes in
     their multibyte form).
```

Honestly the names of all of these functions are pretty bad. WTF is a “coding string”?? Anyway, if we ignore the function names it is easy:

```lisp
(defun convert-rtf-byte (byte)
  (decode-coding-string (unibyte-string byte) 'cp1252))
```

`M-x man cp1252` tells me that decimal 128 is Euro sign; that seems like an easy test. Executing `(convert-rtf-byte 128)` in my scratch buffer gives me `#("€" 0 1 (charset windows-1252))`, which looks just right. You can use `C-x =` to verify that the buffer contains U+20AC, and that it is encoded as `#xE2 #x82 #xAC` (assuming your scratch buffer, like mine, is UTF-8).